# Redirect complete url to another url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Actually i have changed my dynamic urls to static urls. But the strange thing is i have some old urls which are dynamic. Among them the url is `http://www.startonlinegames.com/download.php` . I want this url to redirect to `http://www.startonlinegames.com/download/?page=download` .. for this i have added the following htaccess rule in my htaccess file.

```
Redirect http://www.startonlinegames.com/download.php http://www.startonlinegames.com/download/?page=download
```

but its not working...can anyone suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : and let me know if it works otherwise will try for another

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewriterule ^download.php(.*)$ http://www.startonlinegames.com/download/?page=download$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the immediate response..but its not working...i tried in different browsers..